# Node.js hangs on HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, http, electron

I am currently developing an Electron application which listens to the TCP socket and sends requests to the REST server after receiving data.

For test purposes I use the following code:

```
const net = require('net');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const server = net.createServer(connection => {
  connection.setEncoding('utf8');
  connection.on('data', data => {
    handleData(data).then(() => connection.end());
  });
});

const handleData = data => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => test(1))
    .then(() => test(2))
    .then(() => test(3))
    .then(() => test(4))
    .then(() => test(5));
};

const test = id => {
  return fetch(`https://server.domain.name/api/v1/software/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    });
};

const socketHost = '0.0.0.0';
const socketPort = 1337;
server.listen(socketPort, socketHost);
```

This code hangs on the first request. According to the `tcpdump`, request does not even leave my machine. Strange thing is when I user IP address in URL instead of domain name, requests work fine. So, I suppose this problem is somehow related to DNS lookup. Any ideas?

**Edit:** When running this code in pure Node.js the issue does not appear.

**Edit:** This issue only appears on Linux.